# Dropbear Login attempt for nonexistent user while user exists in the system

Tags: ssh, embedded-linux, dropbear

I wanted to have a **ssh server on my embedded linux system**, so I tried to install **dropbear** by compiling it and installing the binary in the file system. On that embedded system, I use **busybox**. I have authentication enabled (meaning I have root user and another one with theirs passwords set). I don't use `etc/shadow` so the passwords are stored in the `etc/passwd` file.

I generated a rsa private key with the dropbearkey binary which is located in /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key.

I launched dropbear and show the logs in the stdout, everything looks good.

But when I try to ssh the targeted embbeded system with a user : root for example, and I give the right password (I can log in into the system with that password) I have an access denied saying the password is wrong. The error is the same when trying with a normal user.
About the logs of dropbear, when I try to connect I see the message :
**Login attempt for nonexistent user** whereas I give the right username that exists in /etc/passwd file.
It seems dropbear can't achieve to read that file in order to check if the username provided exists in the system.

Do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: try `strace`ing the binary, it possibly can't find a shared library